# APP-ENGINE load data from static json file or load data into the datastore?

Tags: json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

Im new to app-engine. Writing a rest api. Wondering if anyone has been in this dilemma before?

This data that i have is not alot (3 to 4 pages) and but it changes annually.

Option 1: Write the data as json and parse the json file every time a request comes in.

Option 2: Model into objects and throw into the datastore and then retrieve them whenever a requests comes in.

Does anyone know the pros and cons for each of this method or any better solutions if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the answer is it depends.

Here are some of the questions I'd ask myself to make a decision -

- do you want to make the change to the data dependent on a code push?
- is there sensitive information in the data that should not be checked in to a VCS
- what other parts of your system is dependent on this data
- how likely are your assumptions about the data going to change in terms of frequency of updating and size

Assuming the data is small (<1MB) and there's no sensitive information in it, I'd start out loading the JSON file as it's the simplest solution.

You don't have to parse the data on each request, but you can parse it at the top level once and effectively treat it as a constant.

Something along these lines -

```
import os
import json

DATA_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'YOUR_DATA_FILE.json')
with open(DATA_FILE, 'r') as dataFile:
  JSON_DATA = json.loads(dataFile.read())
```

You can then use `JSON_DATA` like a dictionary in your code.

```
awesome_data = JSON_DATA['data']['awesome']
```

In case you need to access the data in multiple places, you can move this into its own module (ex. `config.py`) and import `JSON_DATA` wherever you need it.

Ex. in `main.py`

```
from config import JSON_DATA

# do something w/ JSON_DATA
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @alpeware! VCS wise i alwyas gitignore my data files! In python, how would you "parse it at the top level once and effectively treat it as a constant."?

Comment: @jiachen no problem. I updated the answer with a specific example. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: thanks for the example!! Does this mean that the JSON is parsed and loaded for every HTTP request that comes in?

Comment: No. Assuming you place this at the top or in a separate module, this will be parsed only whenever your code is loaded the first time.